# Check if Local Database is Already Created C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

Almost done with my C# Password Generator/Store. All the passwords are stored in a local encypted database that is hashed and also has a DB password. I am using sql express/compact(whatever it is called) to create the database manually. I was wondering if there was a way to check if a database was already created and has the right tables included. Also is there a way if the DB is not created to tell it to create an encrypted DB? Also have it create a folder in a speceific location too if that is not there also create it and store the DB inside.

Thanks

Comment: does the database exists on a sql server or a physical file? you can just check if the connection exists or if the file exists for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a query like this

```
  IF NOT EXISTS
   (  SELECT [name] 
      FROM sys.tables
      WHERE [name] = 'TableName`
   )
   CREATE TABLE TableName (Col1 int, Col2 int ... )
```

for each table in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there was a way to
>   check if a database was already
>   created

```
Select * from sys.databases Where name = 'YourDatabaseName'
```

Alternative

```
Select * from sys.objects Where name = 'YourDatabaseName'
```

> has the right tables included

```
Select * from sys.tables where name = 'YourTableName'
```

Alternative

```
Select * from sys.objects where name = 'YourTableName'
```

> Also is there a way if the DB is not
>   created to tell it to create an
>   encrypted DB?

```
If Not Exists(Select * from sys.databases Where name = 'YourDatabaseName')
Begin
    --Create your database
End
```

Folder creation is the process during the database creation